# Mathematica Help Browser from Mathematica 5 in new versions of Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

I remember that someone from WRI stated in the [official newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica) that *Mathematica* 7 still has a working old-fashioned Mathematica Help Browser from *Mathematica* 5 for compatibility purposes. But I can not find the post where the code for invoking it is given.

How to invoke and use this legacy Help Browser in new versions of *Mathematica*?

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you are asking for, but remember you have http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/index.html at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment I have found two ways to invoke the legacy Help Browser by clicking a button:

```
DisplayForm@ButtonBox["Preface",
    BaseStyle -> "AddOnsLinkText",
    Active -> True,
    ButtonData :> {"PCT Preface", None}]
```

and

```
DisplayForm@
 ButtonBox[" »", BaseStyle -> "Link", Evaluator -> Automatic, 
  ButtonFunction :> (PacletManager`Package`helpBrowserLookup[#] &), 
  ButtonData -> "Help Browser"]
```

I found that we have the global option [`HelpBrowserSettings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HelpBrowserSettings.html) that specifies settings for the legacy Help Browser.

And we still have working functions `HelpBrowserLookup` and `HelpBrowserNotebook` (now undocumented) and command `FrontEndTokenExecute["RebuildHelpIndex"]` for rebuilding the help index of the legacy Help Browser.

Answer (score 1):

The old browser will show up if you try to look at documentation for packages that were written in the old format.  From the main documentation page, click 'Add-Ons and Packages' at the very bottom-left, and then click on the old package name.  Based on what I have installed, it looks like the old packages will have a little orange square in front of them, instead of a triangle that shows/hides additional information.

The old browser is only used for old documentation.

I assume you're aware of the 'Function Navigator' and 'Virtual Book' which provide alternate ways of navigating the new documentation.

Comment: Thank you! But there should also be a programmatic way to launch the Help Browser and even open a specific documentation page in it. How this can be done?

Comment: One way I just found myself looking on the Cell expression of a cell with little orange square: ``ButtonBox[" »",
   BaseStyle -> "Link",
   Evaluator -> Automatic,
   ButtonFunction :> (PacletManager`Package`helpBrowserLookup[#] & ),
   ButtonData -> "Help Browser"]``

Comment: For new documentation you can use `SystemOpen["paclet:ref/NMinimize"]`.  (I checked this on OS X using 8.0.1.)

Comment: Perhaps this MathGroup [link](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00066.html) on 'How to bring up specific doc page programmatically' might be of interest? In particular the reply of John Fultz.